# Error while starting the VacationRequestSampleApplication with plugin Activiti on Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security, business-process-management, activiti

I'm new on BPM and I tried to install Activiti on my own Grails application.

I've installed the plugin and the security plugin (Spring security and Activiti-spring security), and also the Vacation Request application.

From : http://code.google.com/p/grails-activiti-plugin/wiki/VacationRequestSampleApplication

I logged in, and when i click on Start link, I got this error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'id' on null object
    at ActivitiGrailsPlugin$_addActivitiMethods_closure7_closure29.doCall(ActivitiGrailsPlugin.groovy:130)
    at ActivitiGrailsPlugin$_addActivitiMethods_closure7.doCall(ActivitiGrailsPlugin.groovy:126)
    at vacationRequest.VacationRequestController$_closure2.doCall(VacationRequestController.groovy:36)
    at vacationRequest.VacationRequestController$_closure2.doCall(VacationRequestController.groovy)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have installed plugins in following order

1. activiti-5.8.2
2. spring-security-core-1.2.7.2
3. activiti-spring-security-0.4.6
4. install-vacation-request-sampleapp

And I am getting

```
| Error 2012-03-26 11:07:49,216 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [GET] /test3/vacationRequest/start 
Cannot get property 'id' on null object. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Cannot get property 'id' on null object
    Line | Method
->>  129 | doCall    in ActivitiGrailsPlugin$_addActivitiMethods_closure7_closure29
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    125 | doCall    in ActivitiGrailsPlugin$_addActivitiMethods_closure7
|     36 | doCall .  in vacationRequest.VacationRequestController$_closure2
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

Can it be from version of plugins I am using ?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't face the problem reported by you.

I create the project with the following commands:

```
grails create-app a581
grails install-plugin activiti
grails activiti-quickstart
grails install-vacation-request-sampleapp
```

I guess you may miss some steps. You may try to run the project created by me in your workstation at http://grails-activiti-plugin.googlecode.com/files/a581.zip